# Kакова этимология слова "варяг"? What is the etymology of 'varyag'?

Tags: этимология, история-языка

Имеется в виду буквальное значение слова. The word is meant in its literal sense.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it is just the ethnic name, `Vaeringjar` in Old Islandic or `væringi` in Old Norse. It probably got into Slavic languages via Greek `Βάραγγοι`.

The word itself is probably a compound of `vár` "pledge" and `gengi` "companion", i.e. "a sworn person" or "a foreigner who has taken service with a new lord by a treaty of fealty to him, or protégé".

Source: English and Russian Wikipedia.

Comment: It's not all clear about this etymology. We have a resembling Swedish word 'varg' meaning 'wolf' which differs from Icelandic úlfur, Danish/Norwegian ulv, etc. However, this word is very much like Hugarian 'farkas', Moksha вьрьгаз, Erzyan верьгиз, and common Uralo-Fennic 'ver' (blood).

Comment: @Manjusri - According to the historical development of the Slavic languages, this я in варЯг could't appear out of nothing, it had to develop from a nasalized vowel, which, in turn, had appeared from a vowel + a nasal consonant combination. Texnic's answer fits this development well, but I cannot see the source of this я in the Uralic etymology you propose.

Comment: That could appear from loaned Uralic e/ä as well.

Comment: @Manjusri - But what's the reason for Slavs to call the Northmen "wolves" and to do it in a Finno-Ugric language? Northmen were rather respected and were elected Slavs' princes. Don't you see a logic contradiction here? Besides, Northmen, vikings, never associated themselves with wolves, their totem symbol was the raven.

Comment: There were not just Slaves in Ancient Russia. And speaking about 'respected northmen' or 'their totem' - of which there had been many more types than just raven - is, in my opinion, a mere mythological speculation.

Comment: I could not come through Greek. It enjoys common pattern for Germanic borrowings.